# How can i put the data array gained from the fetch return to the Dropdown component?

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to make a simple dropdown list which data is gained from a fetch return..
if I use console to view the return, it shows like this :

```
[
  {
    "ID": "BOGOR~10"
    "Location": "BOGOR"
  },

  {
    "ID": "JADETABEK~16"
    "Location": "JADETABEK"
  }
]
```

if I want to take the location BOGOR and JADETABEK and put them into a Dropdown, how can I do that? this is my testing class

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { View , StyleSheet , Text , Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';

const ScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const Screenheight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default class testing extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(url , {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"lokasi":
                {

                }
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                data: res.PilihLokasiResult.Lokasi    
            })
            alert(res.PilihLokasiResult.Lokasi)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <Text>{this.state.location}</Text>
                    <Dropdown label="select location" style={{width: 400 }}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the data since [react-native-material-dropdown](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown) accepts data in the form of `{value: 'Sample'}`

```
this.state = {
  data: [],
  dropDownData: []
}

const formatData = (data) => {
  return data.map(dataObj => {
    return {value: dataObj.Location} // return based on location
  })
}

.then(res => {
   const dropDownData = formatData(res.PilihLokasiResult.Lokasi)
   this.setState({
     data: res.PilihLokasiResult.Lokasi,
     dropDownData    
   })
})

<Dropdown label="select location" data={this.state.dropDownData} style={{width: 400 }}/>
```

Comment: where should I put the const formatData? is it under the constructor? sorry i'm a beginner..

Comment: Outside of your component, since it is just a normal formatter function

Comment: I tried to put it outside the export default class, and it throws yellow screen saying 
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0):
TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: Yes, anywhere outside class

Comment: Try to check the result that you've added in the first snippet should be passed to the function, i don't know if that is correct or not